# Randomizing DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random-data

If a create a DataFrame Object, lets say `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5), 'B':range(5)}`, and try to randomize some rows with `df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))` I get

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5), 'B':range(5)})
>>> df
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
>>> df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))
   A  B
3  0  0
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
4  4  4
```

Numpy version is 1.15.0

Pandas version is 0.23.3

Any idea why it is just mixing the indexes and not the whole rows?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you are describing with v0.23.3 but the pandas way to do this is `df.sample(frac=1)`.

Comment: I cant reproduce this either

Comment: What you sure you are using `reindex` and not just re-setting the index by changing `df.index` ?

Comment: The "df.sample(frac=1)" method indeed works, but I want to figure out why the prior method is misbehaving. By the way, I forgot to mention that I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Comment: It's been several month since I asked this, but it seem that now it is behaving correctly (Maybe some Ubuntu update fixed the problem?)